# MS Access 2010 Creating a form from SQL query and master detail relationship

Tags: ms-access, forms, master-detail

Can anyone provide me the steps to create a form that is based on an SQL Query.  I have already compiled a form using the wizard and am working to figure out how to do it based on a SQL Query.  As well as using my own design to create a form using a master detail relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by SQL query?

Do you wish to bind the form to a recordset? If so, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281998.

Do you wish to use an SQL Server view for the Record Source? You can link it: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-to-sql-server-data-HA010200494.aspx

Do you wish to set the Record Source to an SQL string? You can do this manually or through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are probably mistaken in your belief that when you build a master form with one record, and then want to edit some child detail records in access that you have to build a query that joins the two tables together.  I can't stress how wrong this is, and that's not the way most systems will work.

In fact if you are to join the master record to the child table, if you have 10 child records, the master record would also be repeated 10 times in that query, and which of the 10 reproductions of the master record would you thus want to be able to edit?

So you are most certainly free to build a query that's based on the master table, and that query does not need nor is there any requirement to join in any child record data.  Once you build this query, then you are free to use the wizard or simply bring up a form in design mode and drop fields on into the form based on this query.  When you've done that you can save this master form. You now can then build a new query based on the child table. And then again you now build a form based on this child table. Once you've done this, then you can drop the child form into the master form, and you have the same setup as to which the wizard has accomplished.

So in both cases and both approaches there's absolutely no requirement to build a sql query that joins in other tables.  And there's really no particular advantage or even performance advantages to building and basing a form on a query as opposed to the base table.  And for the child form that edits the child table, once again there's no particular advantage or performance issues by basing the child form on the child table directly, or basing it on a query.

So in access to model and edit and maintain parent to child data or master to details as you ask, you DO NOT have to use queries that join in the two tables. So as a general rule will base the form on an query that is the result of one table. As noted it's rather, and an acceptable to base the form directly on the table itself.